# Bevel corner on the z-axis

Tags: bevel

I have the following mesh that has its top edges beveled already, but from a top-down view, all the angles are at 90 degrees, as it is visible from the base of the mesh. I want to make the corner that is the closest to the camera bevelled on the z-axis while keeping the bevel on the top edges, so that when you look at it from above, you perceive the corner as "rounded", as it is indicated by the drawn red lines. The base of the mesh should also become rounded. What's the easiest way to achieve this?

[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: Not sure that you can since that vertical edge appears to already be bevelled.

Comment: It is not actually. If you look at the bottom, you will notice a 90deg angle

Comment: Yes. I noticed that but how could those extra edges appear without a bevel? Agree about beveling that edge before all the others!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to bevel that edge first, then bevel the other edges second:
[image]

If you need to remove the bevels from an existing mesh, check out the Mira Tools addon. But since it's such a simple mesh it would be simpler to just start over.
Also, it looks like your bevels are a bit stretched, this happens when you use the bevel tool without applying scale frist.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the answer and for the extra tips, much appreciated